# htop - how can I enable the new metrics for "delay accounting"?

Tags: htop, capabilities

htop has some new metrics:

> **PERCENT_CPU_DELAY (CPUD%)**
>   The   percentage  of  time  spent  waiting  for  a  CPU  (while  runnable).  Requires
>               CAP_NET_ADMIN.
>
> **PERCENT_IO_DELAY (IOD%)**
>   The percentage of time spent waiting for the completion  of  synchronous  block  I/O.
>               Requires CAP_NET_ADMIN.
>
> **PERCENT_SWAP_DELAY (SWAPD%)**
>   The percentage of time spent swapping in pages. Requires CAP_NET_ADMIN.

Links:

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/htop.1.html
- https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/2.1.0/htop.1.in#L373
- https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/pull/667
- https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/665

I added CAP_NET_ADMIN, I do not know if it's correct.

I still do not see these metrics in the column settings.

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/htop 

$ getcap /usr/bin/htop 
/usr/bin/htop = cap_net_admin+eip
```

EDIT:

 Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

 kernel 4.20.17-042017-generic

No, `sudo htop` doesn't help.

htop 2.1.0 - (C) 2004-2018 Hisham Muhammad
Released under the GNU GPL.

Comment: Thank you for adding the required detail to your question!  Great idea to include the kernel version.  I did not know what you meant to start with, so I have edited to add links that I think will help others.  I *thought* running as `sudo htop` should provide any needed capabilities.  I do not know the answer to your question.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro `sudo htop` works i.e. starts without error, but it does not *help* with this specific problem.  Original wording is clearer.

Comment: This is config files: $HOME/.config/htop/htoprc
Can anyone send me entries with set columns to be visible?
I think that these are the right numbers in the "fields" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile htop source code with `--enable--delayacct` option, then you can see these metrics in the column setting if you have `cap_net_admin` permission.